# Selecionar colunas de umas base sem precisar ler o arquivo todo

Tags: r

Tenho um arquivo em .csv MUITO grande que não consigo ler no R.
Tentei assim:

```
dados19 <- read.csv("microdados_censo_superior_2019/dados/SUP_ALUNO_2019.CSV", sep="|", dec=".")
```

É o censo da educação superior 2019 pode ser encontrado em https://www.gov.br/inep/pt-br/acesso-a-informacao/dados-abertos/microdados/censo-da-educacao-superior

Contudo, eu não preciso do arquivo todo, só de algumas colunas (as colunas que preciso são: CO_CURSO, TP_SEXO, TP_COR_RACA e IN_MATRICULA). Haveria a possibilidade de carregar/ selecionar apenas as colunas que desejo? Sem precisar ler o arquivo todo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dados19 <- read.csv('./SUP_ALUNO_2019.CSV', sep = '|', dec = '.',
               colClasses = c('NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','integer',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','integer',
                              'integer','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','integer',
                              'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'))
```

Colocando NULL no colClasses você não carrega a coluna(pula a coluna). Cada valor desse dentro do array indica uma variável, note que as variáveis que são mantidas estão como integer.

Comment: Deu super certo! Muito obrigada! Sou iniciante e estava há um tempão tentando.

Comment: @AlexsandraGomes, bom dia! Por nada, fico feliz que funcionou, como você é iniciante sempre poste suas dúvidas no site que o pessoal tenta ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: lmonferrari, fui mudar a variável 11 (CO_CINE_ROTULO) colocando 'integer' nela e mostra o seguinte erro: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() esperava 'an integer', obteve '0421D01'. Você tem ideia de como resolver?

Comment: @AlexsandraGomes, boa tarde! Essa coluna é formada por números e caracteres, você deve passar o tipo de dado da coluna como `character`. Abraço!

Comment: @AlexsandraGomes, boa noite! Você digitou `NUL` onde o certo é `NULL`, por isso está dando esse erro. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a [resposta de @lmonferrari](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491126/117168). Como os arquivos de microdados são muito grandes, usarei o conjunto mtcars de exemplo:

```
write.csv(mtcars[1:3,], "exemplo.csv")
```

**data.table**

A função `fread` do pacote *data.table* tem a opção `select` para especificar as colunas desejadas por nomes ou números.

```
library(data.table)

> fread("exemplo.csv", select = c("disp", "wt", "gear"))
   disp    wt gear
1:  160 2.620    4
2:  160 2.875    4
3:  108 2.320    4
```

É mais rápida que `read.table` e faz um bom trabalho determinando automaticamente separador e símbolo decimal (mas podem ser especificados manualmente).

**sqldf**

Importa e lida *data.frames* como banco de dados, com suporte para declarações SQL. No caso da função para ler arquivos, isso pode ser usado não apenas para selecionar colunas mas também linhas por condição.

```
library(sqldf)

> read.csv.sql("exemplo.csv", sql = "select disp,wt,gear from file where carb > 2")
  disp    wt gear
1  160 2.620    4
2  160 2.875    4
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Vou olhar todas essas funções.